# Object under mouse?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl

My little game engine basically has a 3D array Cubes[x][y][z] (its actually a big 1D array but I'v done some overloading). I know which cube in X Y Z that the player is standing on. The player will be able to shoot a cube to destroy it which is why I need to figure out how to find the Cube that the mouse is under. I found some OpenGL documentation on picking, but this method was slow. Since my cubes are organized and I know which cube the player is on, and the camera's angle in X and Y (camera does not rotate on Z), and that the mouse is always at screenwidth / 2, screenheight / 2 I'm sure theres a faster way than the gl picking technique.

Here is how the camera is set up:

```
void CCubeGame::SetCameraMatrix()
{

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(Camera.rotx,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(Camera.roty,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(Camera.rotz,0,0,1);

    glTranslatef(-Camera.x , -Camera.y,-Camera.z );
}

void CCubeGame::MouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    if(!isTrapped)
        return;

    int diffx = x-lastMouse.x; 
    int diffy = y-lastMouse.y; 

    lastMouse.x = x; 
    lastMouse.y = y;
    Camera.rotx += (float) diffy * 0.2; 
    Camera.roty += (float) diffx * 0.2; 
    if(Camera.rotx > 90)
    {
        Camera.rotx = 90;
    }

    if(Camera.rotx < -90)
    {
        Camera.rotx = -90;
    }

    if(isTrapped)
    if (fabs(ScreenDimensions.x/2 - x) > 1 || fabs(ScreenDimensions.y/2 - y) > 1) {
        resetPointer();
    }

}

Vertex3f CCubeGame::MoveCamera( int direction, float amount )
{
    float xrotrad, yrotrad;
    Vertex3f result(0,0,0);

    switch(direction)
    {
    case CAM_FORWARD:
        yrotrad = (Camera.roty / 180 * 3.141592654f);
        xrotrad = (Camera.rotx / 180 * 3.141592654f);

        result.x = float(sin(yrotrad)) * amount;
        result.z = -(float(cos(yrotrad)) * amount);
        result.y = 0;
        //Camera.y -= float(sin(xrotrad)) * amount;
        break;
    case CAM_BACKWARD:
        yrotrad = (Camera.roty / 180 * 3.141592654f);
        xrotrad = (Camera.rotx / 180 * 3.141592654f);
        result.x = -(float(sin(yrotrad)) * amount);
        result.z = float(cos(yrotrad)) * amount;
        result.y = 0;

        //Camera.y += float(sin(xrotrad)) * amount;
        break;
    case CAM_RIGHT:
        yrotrad = (Camera.roty / 180 * 3.141592654f);
        result.x = float(cos(yrotrad)) * amount;
        result.z += float(sin(yrotrad)) * amount;
        result.y = 0;
        break;
    case CAM_LEFT:
        yrotrad = (Camera.roty / 180 * 3.141592654f);
        result.x = -(float(cos(yrotrad)) * amount);
        result.z = -(float(sin(yrotrad)) * amount);
        result.y = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    Camera.x += result.x;
    Camera.y += result.y;
    Camera.z += result.z;

    return result;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't rotate in Z, then you can only shoot a cube at the same Z height that the gun is at.  This makes things a lot simpler because you can sort your cubes by Z and throw away any that are too high or too low (this will take `log(N)` time in the number of cubes if they can be at fractional heights; if they're all the same height and all at the same height as each other, you just index into that portion of the array).

Now you need to draw a line from the gun through the grid and find out which cube it hits first.  The way to do this is with a vector along the line of the gun:

```
v = (cos(angle), sin(angle))
```

and find each boundary where that line crosses an integer in either X or Y.  If we are at

```
(x0,y0)
```

to start with and travel in direction `v` then we will hit (assuming cos(angle) > 0)

```
ceil(x0), ceil(x0+1), ...
```

at times

```
(ceil(x0)-x0)/cos(angle), (ceil(x1)-x1)/cos(angle), ...
```

and similarly for `y0` and `sin(angle)`.  Now you just walk down the list of times--which will take you into a new square--and the first time you encounter a cube, you hit it.

If the cube array is not gigantic, this whole thing should take only a few microseconds on a decent processor (maybe a few hundred or so on an embedded processor).

Comment: Actually regarding the Z height the player can look up and down and the gun is at the center of the player's face which is the center of the screen, also, arnt my cubes already Z sorted? as in cube(5,5,5) is next to cube(5,5,6).